# Page cache inconsistency across browsers

Tags: caching

Ive done all my Wordpress development in Firefox and I am using a caching plugin called W3 Total Cache.

The only problem I'm facing is that in Safari and Chrome, my navigation is being reloaded each time a user works their way through the navigation, I understand this is how the web works, that assets and content are being reloaded with each click. But in FF, its perfect, the nav appears to stay in place while the navigation is extended underneath > see http://spunfilms.samuelcane.com/ then http://spunfilms.samuelcane.com/work and then that pages children. Have a look at the site in Firefox and then in Chrome/Safari.

Has anyone got any ideas why I'm getting this inconsistency across browsers?

Is there a way around it?

Thanks,
Red

Comment: "appears to stay in place" isn't related to caching - it has to do with how the browser renders the page. Also, doesn't W3TC only cache server-side?

Comment: So do you think its just that FF is rendering the page much quicker than the other browsers? Do you think there is anything I can do to try and bring the others up to FF speed?

Comment: W3TC - Improve site performance and user experience via caching: browser, page, object, database, minify and content delivery network support. Suggests its not just server side?

Comment: In that case, I don't think you've set W3TC up correctly. When I load one of your pages, there's no evidence of any client-side caching. HTML pages don't have any cache headers at all, the Date is set to the date of the request, there's no ETag, etc. Currently, your site might be cached server-side by W3TC (to avoid having WP re-build the pages on every request), but that's it. :)

Comment: Ah, I see! thanks very much. Ill dig into that...

Answer (score 1):

By using W3TC plugin in Wordpress, I managed to optimize the site to make the page load almost instantaneous. My problem was that the plugin wasn't configured properly. I took a look at some other sites using the plugin and tried to configure it accordingly.